# How can I prevent others from using my system but still distribute my build with incredibuild?

Tags: incredibuild

How can I prevent others from using my system to build but still distribute my build over the network with incredibuild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the incredibuild tray icon (the incredibuild agent) and select Disable as Helper.

Answer (score 3):

For your information, IncrediBuild will only use idle CPU cycles of your machine (when your machine acts as a Helper). your CPU consumption as a user will always take precedence.
IncrediBuild's Build Helper is being executed as "nice mode" meaning that the operating system will only service it with idle CPU cycles.

In any regards, in order to be able to distribute YOUR builds but prevent others from using your machine as a Helper resource you can "Disable as Helper".
Right click the IncrediBuild tray icon->Disable as Helper.

Disclaimer - the write is CTO at IncrediBuild

Comment: This comment really didn't answer the question that the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent running of /Xoreax/IncrediBuild/BuildHelper.exe
For example just rename it.